# Are there any up to date Mongo GUI's left?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t, mongovue

This type of question has been asked before but needs a serious update. I'm looking for an up-to-date mongodb gui that supports v3.0.x. Ideally it would also support connection to a MongoDB v3.0.x on a `mongos` instance over SSL.

AFAIK, none exist.

The most well maintained one that I've found was Robomongo but that is only supporting MongoDB v2.4 and as far as I can see from the Github, their release for v3.0.x support hasn't had much movement for many months.

Other GUIs, like MongoVue and RockMongo seem even more out of date.

Has anyone seen a good up-to-date GUI?

Answer (score 1):

I am using [MongoChef](http://3t.io/mongochef/) on a regular basis and it seems to be actively maintained.

It does support mongodb 3.0.

Please note that the commercial license is not for free.